# Permit job to be manually run based on `if` and `changes` clause

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following `rules` for one of my jobs:

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
    changes:
      - upstream/**/*.*

  - when: manual
  - allow_failure: false
```

The current behavior is like this (pseudo-code):

```
if (on master or develop) and (there are upstream changes):
  run_job_automatically
else
  permit_running_job_manually
```

I instead want this:

```
if (on master or develop) and (there are upstream changes):
  permit_running_job_manually
else
  dont_show_job
```

where `dont_show_job` refers to not making the job a part of the pipeline in the first place.

In other words, I want the `when: manual` to be combined with the `if` and `changes` clauses instead of serving as an alternative. The job is either allowed to be run manually, or won't show up at all. It should never be run automatically.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the manual block within the `if` block to do what you desire I believe:

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
    changes:
      - upstream/**/*.*
    when: manual
    allow_failure: false
```

Some more [rule attributes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-attributes).